# Simple OpenGL code always causes a segmentation fault (C++ on Ubuntu, virtual machine)

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I just started trying to use OpenGL in C++ for a class(I have previously used it in Java a fair amount).  And I started off trying to write something substantial, I couldn't get that to stop Seg faulting so I wrote this piddly little piece of code which is nearly a line for line copy from an example in the first chapter of the red book.  It also Seg faults.  My question is why.  I have tried both eclipse, and netbeans, I have the glut.h library linked in my projects in both, I am running 64 bit ubuntu 10.4, on a virtual machine using VMWare, gcc and freeglut are both installed, Both netbeans and eclipse will run regular (non OpenGL) C++ code I write without seg faulting.

Anyway here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void init(){
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.75, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
        glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);    //if I comment out this line,
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);  //this line,
    init();  //this line and the glut main loop line it runs without any errors, but why wouldn't it? It's not doing anything now!
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();    //if I comment out just this line I get illegal instruction instead of segfault but I need this line
    return 0;
}
```

> Thread [1] 28944 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)
>     XF86DRIQueryVersion() at 0x7ffff7e7412e     XF86DRIQueryExtension() at
>   0x7ffff7e742c9        0x7ffff7e73c70      0x7ffff7e53ff8      glXGetFBConfigs()
>   at 0x7ffff7e4c71e     glXChooseFBConfigSGIX() at 0x7ffff7e4cd97
>     fgChooseFBConfig() at freeglut_window.c:205 0x7ffff794a8c7
>     fgOpenWindow() at freeglut_window.c:768 0x7ffff794aac8
>     fgCreateWindow() at freeglut_structure.c:106 0x7ffff7948f62 
>     glutCreateWindow() at freeglut_window.c:1,183 0x7ffff794a2a2        main()
>   at Thread [1] 28944 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
>     XF86DRIQueryVersion() at 0x7ffff7e7412e     XF86DRIQueryExtension() at
>   0x7ffff7e742c9        0x7ffff7e73c70      0x7ffff7e53ff8      glXGetFBConfigs()
>   at 0x7ffff7e4c71e     glXChooseFBConfigSGIX() at 0x7ffff7e4cd97
>     fgChooseFBConfig() at freeglut_window.c:205 0x7ffff794a8c7
>     fgOpenWindow() at freeglut_window.c:768 0x7ffff794aac8
>     fgCreateWindow() at freeglut_structure.c:106 0x7ffff7948f62 
>     glutCreateWindow() at freeglut_window.c:1,183 0x7ffff794a2a2        main()
>   at (project stuff here):54 0x40100b

Comment: I am not sure editing the OpenGL out of the title will help much BioBuckyBall, as I specified Ubuntu does not seg fault with basic C++ code only when I include OpenGL elements.  So while you have simplified the title you have also made it less accurate.

Comment: What's the stack trace where the segfault occurs?  Have you checked `glGetError()`?

Comment: Does other OpenGL code run in the same virtual machine?  What's the output of glxinfo?

Comment: When you run the executable, what arguments are you passing?

Comment: ok not exactly sure how to get a stack trace for the segfault but stuff eclipse tells me No source available for "0x7ffff7e73c70" when I run debug mode

Comment: As For glGetError I added checks and prints to print its decimal value between every gl command except begin and end and it isnt printing anything,  Other opengl code I have pasted in has been the same and seg faulted, (except for a few examples that were using currently depreicated methods still, which gave other errors till I corrected them then seg faulted).

Comment: glxinfo gives me name of display: :0.0
Segmentation fault

Comment: Thanks a ton for trying to help, I am a pretty big noob when it comes to anything besides Java, so I appreciate any help even if you have to eventually get to a level where you assume I am an idiot.

Comment: hmmm this seems to be the heart of the problem according to eclipse "Can't find a source file at "freeglut_window.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location."

Comment: How would I go about doing what it is telling me o do? Or is that not what I want to do?

Comment: none and that shouldn't matter because its only using argv[0] as the name of the window which should be the name of the program, since thats generally what argv[0] is.

Answer (score 3):

Could help :
add GLUT_DEPTH in glutInitDisplayMode
Works for me with this flag, and not without (segfault at glutCreateWindow)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have hardware acceleration inside the virtual machine? Check using glxinfo. The crash inside the DRI suggests that you do not.

Comment: name of display: :0.0
Segmentation fault

thats all glxinfo tells me

Comment: I apparently have Accelerate 3D graphics checked in the virtual machine settings, so I think i do?

Comment: The VM might have HW acceleration, but you need your drivers installed in the OS inside the VM.

Comment: I'd make sure that your version of the flgrx matches (or is as close as possible) to the version of Windows drivers.  According to this http://developer.amd.com/drivers/ccc/Pages/default.aspx it appears that you have Catalyst 10.6 drivers installed under Win 7.  I'd update both Windows 7 and Ubuntu to 10.9.  Check out http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Comment: If installing matching drivers doesn't work, it may be simply that this is a known bug:  http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30964  (Not sure what you should do from here.)  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with different code, and using Debian 6.0 remotely from Mac OS X 10.6. The machine in question was using a Radeon HD 5670 card (although this should not be relevant).

Upon closer inspection it seemed that something with OpenGL itself was not working properly, because it was not only my code that failed.

Some of the symptoms I encountered include:

- Programs using OpenGL crash with SIGSEGV at XF86DRIQueryVersion()
- glxinfo/glxgears crashes with SIGSEGV as well

For me the solution was to remove the Radeon fglrx driver (remove all packages with aptitude) and install the 'radeon' driver instead. Then run 'sudo Xorg -configure' to generate a new configuration, test it with 'sudo X -config /root/xorg.conf.new' and copy it to your default xorg.conf location.

After that the the programs did not crash with SIGSEGV anymore, although I got a different error:

- glxinfo gives: Got Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
- glxgears gives: Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

This in turn seemed to be related to direct rendering (DRI) giving trouble. A solution to this was to disable direct rendering by setting 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes'. An alternative is to remove the library used for DRI (in my case this was libgl1-mesa-dri).

I'm still not quite convinced that this is the *whole* solution, since the fglxr drivers shouldn't matter when using only glxinfo and glxgears from a remote terminal. I suspect that  removing fglxr and installing radeon somehow solved something in the configuration.

Some references I used include:

- http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?p=382913#post382913
- http://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo
- https:// discussions.apple.com/message/10140344#10140344
- http:// forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=63730

Comment: It seems the errors are related to the graphics being forwarded over an SSH tunnel (from Mac OS X to Debian 6.0 in my case) which is causing trouble. When using 'direct' rendering, this gives the second set of errors, when using 'indirect' rendering, the opengl programs work again. Also: running glxinfo | grep "renderer string" gives the VGA hardware in my Mac, not the remote machine. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/what-does-libgl-always-indirect-1-actually-do as well.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that if you compile the following pared down example, you'll still get a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("test window");
    return 0;
}
```

Because your segmentation fault is occurring in:

```
fgCreateWindow() at freeglut_structure.c:106 0x7ffff7948f62 glutCreateWindow()
```

In other words, it can't create a window (doesn't matter what's in it).  My guess, along the lines of what @Matias replied is that you need to enable 3D acceleration within your VM?  But it might be a display driver issue, 32 vs 64 bit, or something slightly more sinister such as a mis-match between freeglut & your version of OpenGl -- hence my previous barrage of questions.  Could you re-compile this pared down version and post the results?

Comment: Ahh - and I see from your comments that you're running Ubuntu 10.04 x64 in MS Virtual PC from Win 7 x64?  My guess is that this is another instance of the bugs related to the way they changed the display drivers loading in Win 7.  Did you modify the boot parameters for the install - as "noreplace-paravirt"?  See for instance http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466888 or http://nemesisv.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-ubuntu-904-on-microsoft.html